# How can I scan documents from a Lexmark x543n over the network on OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, drivers, scanning, lexmark-printer, all-in-one

I just got a Lexmark x543dn and have some trouble getting my computer to recognize it as a scanner. The printer is working fine from my OS X 10.6 machine, setup was as easy as it gets. I just connected it to my network, gave it a name and added it under that name as a networked printer in OS X.

According to the [Apple support website](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3669), the driver in OS X (I upgraded to the newest drivers already) should also provide scanning capabilities. However when I run the image capture app included in OS X it tells me that there are no scanners available.

Can anybody tell me what I have to do to get OS X to recognize the scanner?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working as follows on my Lexmark X543. (may not be your desired solution but should serve as a workaround at least.)

1. Got it setup as a printer with the general network setup (and being able to print over the network) (mac-standard-install.html topic)
2. logged onto my router and identified the printer's IP-address.
3. web browsed to the printer's webserver: like http://192.168.1.7 (in my case)
4. Click scan profile in the left hand side menu, choose the settings and scanning destination and start to scan (was using shortcut one for me so I had to press #1 on the scanner.
5. Scanned document was saved on the desired path on my computer, (so it worked very well.)

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the [Lexmark driver](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&id=DR19821&actp=search&viewlocale=es_ES&userlocale=EN_US&segment=SUPPORT&productCode=LEXMARK_X543&searchid=1288150913724).  It was released on 09/29/2010.  The release notes:

> This package installs a TWAIN Data Source (DS) for use with TWAIN-compliant applications for Network Scanning and Image Capture module for direct-attached devices in the Mac OS X system.